# IOS/Objective-C: Send Synchronous request for login

Tags: ios, objective-c, synchronous

Hi I have been sending a login with asynchronous request (as it is commonly advised to use asynchronous where possible) but I now want to make it synchronous to better control when I receive the response.

Can someone suggest how to alter the asynchronous code below to synchronous?

Thanks for any suggestions:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://~/login.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *rq = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [rq setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSData *jsonData = data;
    [rq setHTTPBody:jsonData];
    [rq setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [rq setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
//Want to change to a synchronous request
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:rq queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *rsp, NSData *data, NSError *err) {
        if (err) {
            NSLog(@"Error%@",err);
        } else {
            NSDictionary *jsonResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
                      NSNumber *idResponse = jsonResults[@"response"][@"userid"];
            if (![idResponse isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
                NSInteger userid = [idResponse integerValue];
            }
            }
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //back in main queue to use results of login.

            });
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: How have you lost control using an asynchronous request?

Comment: Right now I have things divided into different methods and have the server call in its own method.  I guess I could rearrange things and put what follows a successful login into the call method, but it would require a ton of refactoring when after all what I really want to do is get the results of the login attempt to determine what comes next.

Comment: I don't see the problem; Cocoa is an event based system unlike other systems.

Comment: True.  Was trying to avoid rewriting a bunch of methods.  Guess I have to bite the bullet as Duncan suggests.

Comment: `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:rq queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` is a bit comical :) You send a request asynchronously to avoid keeping the main thread busy, and then dispatch this request to... the main thread :)

Comment: There is a reason.  But since you are so smart, there is  no need to tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're out of luck.

Apple has deprecated just about all the methods in `NSURLConnection`. We're supposed to start using `NSURLSession` instead, and that is async only.

The take-away is "if you're using synchronous networking, you're doing it wrong."

I think you should probably bite the bullet and do that refactoring. What I do is to create my own methods that take a completion block, and the completion block in NSURLSession calls my methods completion block (from the main thread to make things simple.)

Comment: Ok.  I will give that a try.  Thx!

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple, there is a Sync Request function called

```
+ sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:
```

But also, According to Apple, you should never use it from the main thread of a GUI application(explained in the following link)

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:

The Async you posted, did finally get back to the Main Thread when the call is finished using

```
dispatch_get_main_queue()
```

I would suggest to do some researches on how iOS manage multi-thread using GCD